# Java: While Loop suppresses paint function of JFrame

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, jframe, keylistener

I'm building a custom engine for a dungeon crawler. I have a working KeyLogger that can detect Keystrokes using the KeyListener.

I also have a JFrame c and a function paint() inside the engine that generates the frame and tells c to repaint(). Third of all I have a move() function that changes the players coordinates based on the pressed Keys.

KeyListener:

```
KeyListener kl = new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {

        if (k.getKeyChar() == 'w') {
            my = 1;
        } else if (k.getKeyChar() == 's') {
            my = -1;
        }

        if (k.getKeyChar() == 'a') {
            mx = 1;
        } else if (k.getKeyChar() == 'd') {
            mx = -1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {

        if (k.getKeyChar() == 'w' || k.getKeyChar() == 's') {
            my = 0;
        }

        if (k.getKeyChar() == 'a' || k.getKeyChar() == 'd') {
            mx = 0;
        }
    }

};
```

move():

```
void move() {

    System.out.println("Moving by x: " + mx + " y: " + my);
    player.move(10 * mx, 10 * my);
    paint();

}
```

and the paint() function:

```
public void paint() {


    System.out.println("Paint Engine");

    Graphics g = Frame.getGraphics();

    //Generate Frame

    c.repaint();


}
```

The Class that that runs all of this is called setup:

```
public void setup() {

    LevelGen lg = new LevelGen();
    c.addKeyListener(kl);

    lg.generateLevel(0);

    walls = lg.getWalls();
    player = lg.getPlayer();

    paint(); // does not get executed with the while-loop but without

    while(true){ //Please sebd help
        move();
        paint();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If I put the move() and paint() command in the KeyListener or the main function of the class everything works like a charm but if it's put in a while(true) loop either in the main function, or a new Thread neither the KeyStrokes get detected or the paint() command **infront of** the loop/thread get's executed.

I have also tried removing the Thread.sleep but that changes absolutely nothing. On a quick side note: Alt+F4 also stops working when the loop is added in any way.

I have been stuck on this problem for the past 6 1/2 hours so I might soon be turning insane.

Comment: I guess you probably have trouble with blocking the event dispatcher thread, or by calling methods on it that shouldnt be called on it. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html for example.

Comment: its obvious that you blocked the EDP and the JFK Plus not to Mention...I dont see anything wrong (I dont want anyone telling me the variables are lower case and that junk) so you might as well put up a complete code - but 61/2 hours are a mighty feat